# How to return part of a FileStream from an ASP Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am returning a file from my controller, e.g.:

```
return File(myStream, ...);
```

where *myStream* is a `FileStream`.

Now, I would only like to return part of the file (e.g. from byte position 10 to byte position 100). Are there some built-in methods or classes in .NET that I can use to achieve this?

I don't want to copy things to a `MemoryStream` due to the potential huge memory usage.

Comment: I've removed your ASP.NET Core tag since it's clear from all of your other .NET Framework-centric tags that this question is about ASP.NET (.NET Framework) rather than ASP.NET Core. If that isn't correct, feel free to fix your tags.

Comment: As for your problem, I would suggest looking into creating your own derived `ActionResult`. You can see the code for the existing `FileStreamResult` [here](https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/FileStreamResult.cs).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-2.0?view=aspnetcore-5.0#enhanced-http-header-support